# Post job offer background check

Tags: background-check

I was offered a position at a big company a couple of weeks ago.  My start date is next Monday, the 24th.  My background check has been ongoing. I messed up a date on a job that I worked for years ago, but I didn't lie about the length of the time I worked there (wondering how bad this is, can I fail?). They had trouble verifying my one of my jobs, but after I provided references, I haven't heard any issues of the topic. Because I start Monday, and I haven't been given an update on my background check, does this mean I might have failed? I have no criminal history, and almost a perfect credit score, but the process of providing all of my correct information was a little rocky. I'm scared that I quit my current job and that I might be getting a failed background.

Please don't respond by saying you shouldn't of quit, this is a lesson learned, believe me.

Comment: *I messed up a date on a job* - Did you already tell them or was that the job you were able to give references on?

Comment: They asked me and I explained that it was an honest mistake.  I also made it clear that I didn't lie about the amount of time I worked at the job.

Comment: They asked, you answered, honestly.  Unless it casts doubt about your alibi during the JFK shooting, or otherwise puts you in a negative light, you're probably fine.  Getting the starting or ending month slightly wrong on a position three jobs and a dozen years ago where you accurately portrayed the length of time there does not fall under that category.

Answer (score 6):

> Because I start Monday, and I haven't been given an update on my
>   background check- does this mean I might of failed?

Quite the opposite - it most likely means you have passed.

If you failed the background check, virtually every employer would notify you and tell you not to bother to show up for work.

Since that hasn't happened, it almost certainly means you are good to go. No company would want to waste time having you come in and then tell you that you aren't hired.

Anything is possible, and you'll likely find out soon enough. But if it were me, I wouldn't be so worried. At this point, there isn't much you can do about it anyway.

> Please don't respond by saying you shouldn't of quit, this is a lesson
>   learned, believe me.

Okay, I won't. Sounds like there is a lesson there for others as well.

Comment: I don't know of any companies that would extend an offer, let alone schedule a start date without a successful background check. The ONLY thing that comes to mind would be a government security clearance.

Comment: @DLS3141 even then, you don't get in the door without that clearance.

Comment: @SaggingRufus plenty of people get new jobs and go to work for employers while their security clearance is in process. They just can't work on anything that requires the clearance, but they can be trained and do other things

Comment: @JoeStrazzere sure, but that date is tentative pending the bg check.

Comment: @DLS3141 Happened to me at a Fortune 10 telco where I work now. The BC took almost a month so they kept having to push it back.  It happens.

Comment: There's no way I'd give notice and leave one job for another until the  i's were dotted and the t's crossed on something so basic as a BG check. Records get screwed up all the time. Two or three weeks into a new job is not the time to find out your identity has been stolen and there are 6 warrants out for you in Tampa even though you haven't been to Florida in 20 years. Let's get that ironed out first.

Answer (score 0):

It's very unlikely that you would be starting on Monday and they haven't notified you one way or another. Because you aren't lying about the work experience and provided proper references to prove it, there wouldn't be an issue even if they contacted you about a failed background check. You could just explain you accidentally messed up one of the dates, and set everything straight from there - the company is clearly interested in hiring you after all.

Honestly, if you're still worried - just contact them. It may seem like your credibility will take a hit admitting an accidental wrong date, but being upfront and honest with an employer is **very** important.